# Notification of server connection problems in chat rooms is annoying

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Could you stop notifying that the internet connection has problems with a big drop down bar which I have to dismiss with a click every time? Or can you make it optional, if the user wants to see these bars?

I know myself, that I have a crappy internet connection and it will not improve the situation, if you remind me every ten seconds.

Comment: Connect harder!

Comment: @ran: I could say it is a French Connection, but that would be a lie.

Comment: +1 from someone else who uses TCP over carrier pigeon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess *at very least* we should dismiss this automatically when your client *does* connect.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea :) Will test it, as soon as chat is available again. So next year or something like that ...